# Youtube video upload using NSURLRequest

Tags: ios, video, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to upload the video to youtube using NSURLRequest.
I am able to authenticate and the user and also video gets uploaded, and when checked it says **Failed (unable to convert video file)** i am not getting what to do, Please usggest

constructed request

```
Authorization = "Bearer ya29.AHES6ZTQ3rJZaf2g3pIYa_7_myg1N_GvQ4VdmJIcapfoqKIfQf-Iow";
Connection = close;
"Content-Length" = 1848078;
"Content-Type" = "multipart/related; boundary=217NH17UDP";
"GData-Version" = 2;
Host = "uploads.gdata.youtube.com";
Slug = "videoFile.mp4";
"X-GData-Key" = "key=AI39si4b-ta8ku-hbsLt73O0rIlOBjpHbITt8WGrwL7OevwjNjl5EFcowlJlBM6kp3rrU1cw64Vobp1l1lJP31Rqavshl4962A";

--217NH17UDP
Content-Type: application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"
xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">
<media:group>
    <media:title type="plain">Sample Video File</media:title>
    <media:description type="plain">
        Description of the sample video
    </media:description>
    <media:category
        scheme="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat">Music
    </media:category>
    <media:keywords>Keywords</media:keywords>
</media:group>
</entry>
--217NH17UDP
Content-Type: video/mp4
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

Video data (NSData)

--217NH17UDP--
```

as specified in "https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_direct_uploading#Direct_uploading",

Please suggest...

Answer (score 0):

You may wanna set content_type as video/*

Comment: Thanks, Thats not the reason, It is working fine now. Actually i was missing the format of the post, It checks even a single space difference in the post data is treated as invalid,

Answer (score -1):

It works fine only if you implement the request exactly as specified (even a single space matters)

Finally able to upload the video, Here the 200% working code.

```
NSString* const kMetaData = @"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\r\n<entry xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\"\r\nxmlns:media=\"http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/\"\r\nxmlns:yt=\"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007\">\r\n<media:group>\r\n<media:title type=\"plain\">%@</media:title>\r\n<media:description type=\"plain\">\r\n%@\r\n</media:description>\r\n<media:category\r\nscheme=\"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat\">%@\r\n</media:category>\r\n<media:keywords>%@</media:keywords>\r\n</media:group>\r\n</entry>\r\n";


- (void)uploadVideo:(NSString *)videoFilePath videoInfo:(NSDictionary*)inVideoInfo
{
    NSData* videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:videoFilePath];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kVideoUploadURL]];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

    //header values
    [request setValue:kHostHeaderFiels_Upload_Value forHTTPHeaderField:kHostHeaderField_Key];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", self.tokenType, self.accessToken] forHTTPHeaderField:kAuthorizationHeaderField_Key];
    [request setValue:@"2" forHTTPHeaderField:kGdataVersionHeaderField_Key];
    [request setValue:videoFilePath.lastPathComponent forHTTPHeaderField:kSlugHeaderField_key];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:kContentTypeHeaderField_Upload_Value, kBoundary_Value] forHTTPHeaderField:kContentTypeHeaderField_Key];
    [request setValue:kConnectionHeaderField_Value forHTTPHeaderField:kConnectionHeaderField_Key];
    [request setValue:kGdataKeyHeaderField_Value forHTTPHeaderField:kGdataKeyHeaderField_Key];

    //Post Data
    NSMutableData* httpBodyData = [NSMutableData data];

    [httpBodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", kBoundary_Value] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [httpBodyData appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSString *title, *descrition, *keywords, *category;

    title = [inVideoInfo objectForKey:kVideoTitle];
    descrition = [inVideoInfo objectForKey:kVideoDescription];
    keywords = [inVideoInfo objectForKey:kVideoKeywords];
    category = [inVideoInfo objectForKey:kVideoCategory];

    NSString* metaData = kMetaData;
    metaData = [NSString stringWithFormat:metaData, title, descrition, category, keywords];

    [httpBodyData appendData:[metaData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; //Meta Data

    [httpBodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", kBoundary_Value] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; //boundary string
    [httpBodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: video/%@\r\n", videoFilePath.pathExtension] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [httpBodyData appendData:[@"Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [httpBodyData appendData:videoData];
    [httpBodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", kBoundary_Value] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", httpBodyData.length] forHTTPHeaderField:kContentLengthHeaderField_Key];

    request.HTTPBody = httpBodyData;

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue new]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
                               if(connectionError || data == nil)
                               {
                                   self.uploadHandler(NO, nil);
                               }
                               else
                               {
                                   NSXMLParser *xmlparser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
                                   xmlparser.delegate = self;
                                   [xmlparser parse];
                               }
                           }];
}
```