# How like/dislike youtube video ios

Tags: ios, youtube-api

How i can like/dislike youtube video from my iOS app? I read the documentation, but i can't understand, how make it.

```
POST /feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_ID/ratings Host: gdata.youtube.com Content-Type: application/atom+xml Content-Length: CONTENT_LENGTH Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN GData-Version: 2 X-GData-Key: key=DEVELOPER_KEY

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
       xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">   <yt:rating value="like"/> </entry>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use youtube API for rating the video. YouTube currently uses a rating system that lets users indicate whether they like or dislike a video. Here is the link 
 https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_ratings

Comment: i read this documentation, but i don't know how make request.

Comment: refer to this url for contracting request http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19698807/youtube-video-upload-using-nsurlrequest

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a POST request to

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/rate
```

And you need to submit the following parameters:

```
rating: like or dislike (or 'none' to remove the rating from the video)
id: The ID of the video
```

Your call should look like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/rate?rating=like&id=E6UTz_Doic
```

You need you user to have authorized your application via OAuth 2.0 in order to succesfully make a POST call to YouTube's API

You should use [Google's API Client Libraries](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client) to make the calls and easily setup the authentication.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/rate